# laravel validation method returns an error

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to validate some inputs using this :

```
$request->validate([
        'prenom' => 'required',
        'nom' => 'required',
        'telephone' => ['required | regex:/^(?:(?:(?:\+|00)212[\s]?(?:[\s]?\(0\)[\s]?)?)|0){1}(?:5[\s.-]?[2-3]|6[\s.-]?[13-9]){1}[0-9]{1}(?:[\s.-]?\d{2}){3}$/|digits:10'],
        'password' => 'required |string|min:8|confirmed',
        'confirm_pass' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|string|unique:users'
            ]);
```

but it gives me an error:

> Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequired|Regex does
> not exist.

please any idea how to fix it ?!

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @MhluziBhaka laravel 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipe `|` sign is available in your regular expression pattern so it's conflicting with the separator. When using the regex pattern, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, change your code to :

```
'telephone' => array(
      'required',
      'regex:/^(?:(?:(?:\+|00)212[\s]?(?:[\s]?\(0\)[\s]?)?)|0){1}(?:5[\s.-]?[2-3]|6[\s.-]?[13-9]){1}[0-9]{1}(?:[\s.-]?\d{2}){3}$/',
      'digits:10'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Validator;
```

add on top of controller

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what makes you think that any class `Validator` exists in the root namespace?

Answer (score 0):

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
        'prenom' => 'required',
        'nom' => 'required',
        'telephone' => ['required | regex:/^(?:(?:(?:\+|00)212[\s]?(?:[\s]?\(0\)[\s]?)?)|0){1}(?:5[\s.-]?[2-3]|6[\s.-]?[13-9]){1}[0-9]{1}(?:[\s.-]?\d{2}){3}$/|digits:10'],
        'password' => 'required |string|min:8|confirmed',
        'confirm_pass' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|string|unique:users'
            ]);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what have you changed, and why?